# Siemens Logo! 8 <-> pymodbus

Tags: python-3.x, pymodbus, siemens

Using Siemens Logo!Soft Comfort, I want to connect a Siemens Logo! (8) with pymodbus

Settings on a network input on siemens soft comfort (I also tried Unit ID 255 and Modbus Type "DI" (Digital input))

[image: Settings on siemens soft comfort (I also tried Unit ID 255 and Modbus Type "DI" (Digital input))]

Pc Settings, (I have tried both Interfaces)
[image: Pc Settings, (I have tried both Interfaces)]

Pymodbus code:

```
import time

client = ModbusTcpClient('192.168.0.3')
print(client.connect())
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(client.write_coil(1, True))
    time.sleep(1)
    print(client.write_coil(1, False))
```

The output:

```
True
Modbus Error: [Input/Output] [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Modbus Error: [Input/Output] [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to connect to the Logo via PC, either with the Logo acting as a Modbus server or a Modbus client.

## LOGO! as a Modbus server:

Add a server connection:

[image]

Leave the options completely empty:

[image]

You should then see a little yellow socket at the bottom of the logo:

[image]

No further configuration is needed (the Diagram Editor can be left empty)

Push this configuration to the Logo:

[image]

Send modbus-tcp-messages to the Logo, as described in the original post. The coils to target are described in the Logo!-Settings (they start at 1, while pymodbus starts at 0, so you need to subtract 1:
[image]
[image]

So if we want to turn on the Q1:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

client = ModbusTcpClient('192.168.0.3') # Default port is 502
client.write_coil(address=8192, value=True) # Default unit_id is 1
```

## LOGO! as Client

Add a Client connection:

[image]

Enter the values you want to read:

[image]

Run a modbus server, see [Documentation](https://pymodbustcp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/package/class_ModbusServer.html)